# ST(structure text) transfer data from hex to decimal

Tags: encryption, hex, decimal, plc, st

I need to transfer data from hex to decimal. Data I get as a string. Can someone help with this? Is it possible with ST make it?

Thanks.

Comment: Which PLC are you using?

Comment: Structure text(ST) in OpenPCS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dec_data:= 'ABCD';
    pVar := &iIntVar;
    usiRes:= STR_TO_BIN(Dec_data, pVar, 'X');
    strResult := BIN_TO_STR(pVar,'d');
```

As result is STRING '43981'

Answer (score 0):

```
data:= "005BE045";
    j := 7.0;
    result :=0.0;
    FOR i:=1 TO 8 BY 1 DO
            data2 := MID(data,L:=1,P:=i);
            IF(data2 = '0') THEN
                count := 0.0*(16.0**j);
            ELSIF(data2 = '1') THEN
                count := 1.0*(16.0**j);
            ELSIF(data2 = '2') THEN
                count := 2.0*(16.0**j);             
            ELSIF(data2 = '3') THEN
                count := 3.0*(16.0**j); 
            ELSIF(data2 = '4') THEN
                count := 4.0*(16.0**j); 
            ELSIF(data2 = '5') THEN
                count := 5.0*(16.0**j);
            ELSIF(data2 = '6') THEN
                count := 6.0*(16.0**j);
            ELSIF(data2 = '7') THEN
                count := 7.0*(16.0**j);
            ELSIF(data2 = '8') THEN
                count := 8.0*(16.0**j);
            ELSIF(data2 = '9') THEN
                count := 9.0*(16.0**j);
            ELSIF(data2 = 'A') THEN
                count := 10.0*(16.0**j);
            ELSIF(data2 = 'B') THEN
                count := 11.0*(16.0**j);
            ELSIF(data2 = 'C') THEN
                count := 12.0*(16.0**j);
            ELSIF(data2 = 'D') THEN
                count := 13.0*(16.0**j);
            ELSIF(data2 = 'E') THEN
                count := 14.0*(16.0**j);
            ELSIF(data2 = 'F') THEN
                count := 15.0*(16.0**j);
            END_IF;
            j := j-1.0;
            result:= result + count;
    END_FOR;
    astrDisplayText_20x4[4] := STR(result);
```

Only this way...new function I made and this is works! What do you think?